# What EU preparations does Christine Lagarde propose for a Trump presidency in the areas of 'capital market union' and 'single market', and why?

Tags: european-union, economy, central-bank

In CNN's January 31, 2024 [ECB President: I don't regret warning about Donald Trump](https://youtu.be/tbGGtJr_O40?t=260) where CNN's Richard Quest interviews European Central Bank President [Christine Lagarde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_Lagarde) there is this exchange after about 04:20 (some formatting, emphasis, punctuation and light editing of apparent auto-transcription errors added):

> QUEST: I've read your words -- on what you said about the election of Donald Trump -- very carefully, and on one level, it's unimpeachable, pardon the phrase, in the sense that you were merely stating the obvious. If he's elected, he has a range of policies that will be very difficult for the European values. *But the fact that you said it* - the mere fact that you said it where most people are running for the hills to say nothing controversial. Do you regret saying that?
>
> LAGARDE: No, I don't.
>
> QUEST: Is it that much of a threat to European values?
>
> LAGARDE: I don't, because first of all, I think that being constantly politically correct and perfect in that respect is (at) risk of not seeing the reality and preparing for it. And i think that if you look at what those (years) where when Trump - when Mr. Trump was president of the united states, looking at his program now, shouldn't prevent you from understanding that **there could be threats, and there could be issues for which the europeans should be prepared.**
>
> QUEST: **What sort of preparation are you imagining?**
>
> LAGARDE: **Let me give you two examples here.** The first one is what I call the capital market union, transforming access to finance for SMEs, small, medium sized enterprises, for large(?) corporates, moving away from lending and more to equity in order to facilitate and encourage innovation.
>
> Second example, we have something that is called here, 'the single market'. *Well, it's only a 'single' to a point,* because when you look at some services, for instance, *it is not yet single.* You need to have an equivalent, you need to have a license, you need to do this-and-that which is different, whether you want to apply (those) professional skills (whether you are) in Germany or in Finland, or in France. So the benefit of being more (of), and (then) really a single market is tremendous.
>
> And I think we have to just move in that direction. That's how Europe moves by the way. when it is under threat. So good, let's move!

I would not expect that Lagarde is choosing to reveal new policies, proposals or advice on Quest Meets Busines, she's most likely referring to things she or others in the [European Central Bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Central_Bank) previously articulated.

**Question:** Is it possible to explain to someone unfamiliar with the ECB and the EU's economics

1. What these two examples of preparations actually mean in (at least fairly) simple terms?
2. How or why she sees them as preparation specifically for another potential Trump presidency?

Comment: Do you mostly want to know what kind of policies she is referring to or also how these might relate to a possible president Trump (and by implication somehow have a different impact under a possible president Biden).

Comment: @quarague I'd intended it to be both but that wasn't clear, so I've made an edit. *Thanks!*

Comment: TBH, it's pretty nebulous, but I get a couple of vibes/points from that: (1) US might "go crazy" and decouple from the EU too, (2) EU needs more innovation anyhow. So [she's] using the threat (1) to encourage (2). "moving away from lending and more to equity" could mean other things too, like more state intervention/ownership, which might be different from that though. So, not terribly clear what she means.

Comment: It's also not clear whose equity she's talking about: if it's the ECB's, then that's some Bank of Japan like programme of "owning the economy", which is hard to say how well is working.

Comment: @Fizz thanks, so it's not just me.